# IndexError: list index out of range con requests y api key

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Ayuda, meda este error al correr el código de abajo, corría el codigo hace unos meces sin problema pero hoy me salto ya error, no se si sea por versión de python tenia el 3.6 ahora tengo el 3.7, o por la api_Key:
~

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f87ef028e39c> in <module>
      8 with requests.Session() as s:
      9     r = s.get('https://www.wunderground.com/bundle-universal/index.d10d5f637f8cba449c4f.js')
---> 10     api_key = p.findall(r.text)[0]
     11     start_year = date_ranges[0]
     12 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

~
~

```
  import requests, re
  import pandas as pd

    p = re.compile(r'n\.key="(.*?)"')
    date_ranges = [str(year) + '0101' + str(year) + '1231' for year in range(2019, 1971,-1)]
    results = {}

    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get('https://www.wunderground.com/bundle- 
    universal/index.d10d5f637f8cba449c4f.js')
        api_key = p.findall(r.text)[0]
        start_year = date_ranges[0]

        for year in date_ranges:
            r = s.get(f'https://api- 
 ak.wunderground.com/api/{api_key}/history_{year}/lang:EN/units:english/bestfct:1/v:2.0/q/MMMX.json?showObs=0&ttl=120').json()
            data = r['history']['days']
            if start_year == year:
                columns = list(data[0]['summary'].keys())
            if data:
                for day in data:
                    row = {column:day['summary'][column] if column !='date' else day['summary']['date']['iso8601'][:10] for column in columns}
                    results[row['date']] = row
            else:
                row = {column:None for column in columns}
                results[year] = row
```

~

Comment: Deberías agregar `if r.status_code == 200:` y por el `True` poner tu código, ya que en tu caso, la respuesta que obtienes es 404 >> `404 File Not Found`

Comment: tienes mucha razón me manda esto en la pagina de wunder Request URL: https://api.weather.com/v3/aggcommon/v3alertsHeadlines;v3-wx-observations-current;v3-location-point?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&language=en-US&units=m&format=json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema se origino por que cambiaron el archivo json del cual sacaba la apikey y lo pude solucionar cambiando el código y quedo de la siguiente forma:

```py
utc = pytz.utc
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
        est_tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
                    r = requests.get(f'https://api.weather.com/v1/location/MMMX:9:MX/observations/historical.json?apiKey={apikey}&units=e&startDate={X}&endDate={Y}')
        df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['observations'])
        df['valid_time_gmt'] = df['valid_time_gmt'].map(lambda x: 
get_est_localtime(x).strftime(fmt))
        df = df.groupby(by='valid_time_gmt').agg([min, max, np.mean])
    data_frames.append(df)
```